# phonegap JavaScript canvas doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I've found a simple JavaScript bouncing ball animation, it works on chrome browser (PC)
When I run it, using Phonegap eclipse android emulator it compiles but canvas is blank and the following message displayed "unfortunately system ui has stopped"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

<script>
var context;
var x = 100;
var y = 100;
var radius = 20;
var dx = 5;
var dy = 5;

function init(){
    context = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

    //Set an interval for the canvas to be refreshed.
    // Basically call the draw function every 10 ms
    setInterval(draw, 10);
}

function draw(){
    //Clear the old circle before we draw the new one
    context.clearRect(0,0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height); //This erases the entire canvas

    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "#0000ff";

    //Draw a circle of radius 20 at the current coordinates on the canvas. 
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();

    //Check boundaries and negate if necessary
    if (x + radius <= 0 || x - radius <= 0 || x + radius >= myCanvas.width || x - radius >= myCanvas.width)
        dx = -dx;
    if (y + radius <= 0 || y - radius <= 0 || y + radius >= myCanvas.height || y - radius >= myCanvas.height)
        dy = -dy;

    //Increment dx,dy
    x+=dx;
    y+=dy;
}
</script>


<title>Ball Bouncing</title>

</head>
<body onLoad = "init();"> <!-- when the body is loaded, call the init() function -->
<canvas id = "myCanvas" width ="500" height = "400">
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Also for some reason it works if i remove the following:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
```

ok so i removed

```
  <body onLoad = "init();">
```

and added

```
   document.addEventListener("deviceready",init,false);
```

and i get the following logcat:

```
     09-23 21:53:30.886: E/Web Console(796): Uncaught SyntaxError: "Unexpected token < at   file:///android_asset/www/index.html:7" whats is wrong ?
```

please help

Comment: I think it is some completely different. Please take a look at the android log. Should be a new view "Android LogCat" or something like this. I would guess a "ClassNotFound" or an error regarding the installed html-file.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

<script>
var context;
```

Maybe the second script-tag is causing the problem?

---

There is a line missing like:

```
myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
```

Comment: context = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

Comment: Learned something new, thanks. I always get the element first, like explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp). Seems that isn't necessary.

Comment: Updated my answer because I'm not sure about the second script-tag.

Comment: Hey, have you found the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The html-canvas element should work fine with android. Try the "standard" browser from the android device (not chrome) and test the URL. Cordova uses this browserengine and not chrome.

If that works it is probabaly the app-initialization.

Don't use `onLoad()` in a caordova application. Before you do anything you have to wait for [deviceready-event](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready).

In your `init()` register for `documenready` and start your draw-timer within that event-handler.

Something different:
Use [requestAnimationFrame()](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671) it is better for mobile devices, because you wull only repaint within the default paint-loop. Also only paint if needed (maybe if currently touched), you will suck the battery empty, if you always repaint.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i just don't understand if i wont use onLoad() how would it work

Comment: still doesn't work this way:  function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", init(), false);
    }

Comment: ok si i removed <body onLoad = "init();"> and added document.addEventListener("deviceready",init,false);                       and i get the following logcat: 09-23 21:53:30.886: E/Web Console(796): Uncaught SyntaxError: "Unexpected token < at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:7" whats is wrong ?@ChristianKuetbach